# What is <cc-snippet> in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across `<cc-snippet insert-after"#someid .someclass>` when trying to implement some codes to a website and I couldn't seem to find any documentation of this tag anywhere. Does anyone know what this tag is?

This is a piece of HTML code and I have tried running it on a browser but nothing shows up. I do know that Adobe Dreamweaver uses Creative Cloud (CC), is that what it is?

```
<cc-snippet insert-after="#someid .someclass">
     ......
</cc-snippet>
```

I am not sure what to expect with this tag but I would assume this would behave something like a `<div>` tag.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at a custom component. This was used years ago to declare random styling in a page. For instance `<Red>red text</Red>` isn't using an HTMLElement, it's a random name that can then be used to declare stylized syntax. Problem is,  in your question,  it clearly has attributes. Attributes of randomly named tags have to be parsed by JavaScript to be useful. In Vue and React these are preprocessed by the Browser or file system. Likely it's custom JS. I would suggest searching the original code for a function or code section that does so.

Comment: @zfrisch [custom elements](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) are very much a modern thing and not something from "years ago", nor are they "random".

Comment: @Herohtar .. yeah, they are from years ago. They weren't defined in the language, but HTML was parsed and allowed stylized CSS for those elements that were in the markup that weren't defined. The current standard has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @zfrisch Thank you, I didn't know why I have not thought of that earlier. That must be what it is, though I couldn't seem to find the definition for the custom element in JavaScript. Perhaps that was what is missing from the codes. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Well, it turns out the guy wrote a comment in the style of HTML tag.  So in short, those are comments that should be deleted.